# CQL: Invalid set literal for values of type map

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3

I have this table

```
create table constants_values
              (
               key_name_1 text,
               key_name_2 text,
               values map<text, frozen<nav_tag_values>>,
               PRIMARY KEY(key_name_1, key_name_2)
              );
```

UDT:

```
 CREATE TYPE ks_mobApp.nav_tag_values (
               values set<text>
              );
```

Here i am inserting values:

```
cqlsh:ks_mobapp> insert into constants_values(key_name_1,key_name_2,values) 
values('Sell', 'Electronics', {{'Mobile', {values:{'Laptop'}}}});
```

and here is error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] 
message="Invalid set literal for values of type map<text, nav_tag_values>"
```

What i am missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with **cqlsh**:

```
INSERT INTO constants_values(key_name_1,key_name_2,values) 
VALUES('Sell', 'Electronics', {'Mobile': {value : ['Laptop']});
```

Comment: query is correct except `['Laptop']` should be `{'Laptop'}`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO constants_values(key_name_1,key_name_2,values)  values('Sell', 'Electronics', {'Mobile': {values:{'Laptop'}}});
```

the key point is the : vs the , in your original statement.